# Is there any way to create a library or framework written in Swift that doesn't expose source?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, static-libraries, xcode8

my questions are those five:

1. Can I write static library by using swift ??
2. Can I use a static library that is coded by swift?
3. Can I use a static library that  is coded by objective-c?
4. It seems like from xcode 8, static library is only coded by objective-c(no choice to swift),.... Then I code static library with objective-c,
   Dose it can be used full swift based project (the project's target SDK is iOS 8) ?
5. Is there any way to create a library or framework written in Swift that doesn't expose source?
   Thanks

Answer (score 4):

1. No, you have to use framework for swift
2. There's no static library coded by swift
3. Yes
4. Yes, you can use any kind of Obj-C code in swift
5. Create dynamic framework using swift will hide your source with proper use of access keyword

Comment: Thanks . Using access keyword we can hide the access of method or variable out side the class ,m I right?. But my requirement is to hide the implementation of the class or method from the user of my framework.. If is there any way to do that.?

Comment: After you created a framework with Swift, based on your keyword, XCode will generate a header file that contains them for you, so basically all your swift file are not exposed, only the one you marked with `public` are exposed on the header file